# Ordenação por campo no Power BI

Tags: powerbi, business-intelligence

Tenho três campos no meu `Cartão de linha múltipla` (Essa é a tradução em português): Conta, saldo e % venda. Porém preciso fazer uma ordenação pelo campo ordem, que não se encontra no `Campos` do objeto.

Alguém sabe como fazer? Preciso saber dessa maneira, ou, como ele manter a mesma ordenação do meu select, pois utilizei `UNION ALL` na cláusula. O `Power BI` não está mantendo a mesma ordenação do select.

Comment: Você quer que o PowerBI faça a ordenação por um campo que não consta nas informações, é isso?

Comment: Isso. O meu select trás ordenado do geito que eu quero, porém, ao adicionar os meus campos no card, ele reordena por um dos campos do card, não quero isso.

Comment: poderia explicar melhor oq vc quer??